# What is the most efficient way to find rows of a CSV not containing duplicate entries across the fields of that row (excluding blank entires)?

Tags: python, bash, perl, csv, awk

I'm looking to find all of the rows of a CSV file that contain the duplicate data in two or more of the fields of that row (i.e. find all of the rows without unique data in each field.)

For example, I have the following CSV file:

```
John,Smith,Smith,21
Mary,Jones,Smith,32
John,42,42,42
Henry,Brown,Jones,31
Mary,,,21
```

I would want the following rows to be printed:

```
John,Smith,Smith,21
John,42,42,42
```

These rows are printed because a the data in one field of these rows occurs in another field. Note that "Mary,,,21" was not printed even though it has duplicate empty fields.

I could write a Python script and keep a count of the times each entry occurs in each row, but it seems like there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -F, -lane 'my %s; print if grep { $s{$_}++ } @F'
```

Uses:

- `-F,` to set field separator to `,`
- `-l` to automatically handle linefeeds
- `-a` to autosplit
- `-n` to wrap it in a `while ( <> ) {` loop.
- `-e` to specify code to exec.

Incoming data is autosplit on `,` into `@F` and we use a `%s` hash to spot if there's a dupe.

If — based on your comment — you need to skip empty fields (which this would count as dupes):

```
perl -F, -lane 'my %s; print if grep { /./ ? $s{$_}++ : () } @F'
```

This includes a ternary operator to test if a field is empty.

Testing with Windows (which isn't quite the same, because of quotes):

```
C:\Users\me>perl -F, -lane "my %s; print qq{line matches:$_} if grep { /./ ? $s{$_}++ : () } @F"
line matches:John,Smith,Smith,21
line matches:John,42,42,42
```

If written longhand, it looks more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
   my %seen;
   chomp($line); 
   my @fields = split /,/, $line; 
   if ( grep { /./ and $seen{$_}++ } @fields ) { 
       print $line,"\n";
   }
}

__DATA__
John,Smith,Smith,21
Mary,Jones,Smith,32
John,42,42,42
Henry,Brown,Jones,31
Mary,,,21
```

You could use the `Text::CSV` module to parse it, but I would suggest not doing so, unless you're *specifically* dealing with quoting/embedded linefeeds etc.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Text::CSV; 

my $csv = Text::CSV -> new ( {sep_char => ',', eol => "\n", binary => 1} ); 

while ( my $row = $csv -> getline ( \*DATA ) ) {
   my %seen; 
   if ( grep { /./ and $seen{$_}++ } @$row ) { 
       print join ",", @$row, "\n";
   }
}

__DATA__
John,Smith,Smith,21
Mary,Jones,Smith,32
John,42,42,42
Henry,Brown,Jones,31
Mary,,,21
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -F, '{delete a; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i!="") if ($i in a) {print; next} else a[$i]}' file

John,Smith,Smith,21
John,42,42,42
```

Comment: This works great except for matching on duplicate empty fields. I apologize! I should have been more specific. Is there a way to do this without matching on empty fields?

Comment: That can be easily taken care by adding `if ($i!="")` condition. Check updated answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F, '{delete seen; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( ($i!="") && seen[$i]++ ) { print; next } }' file
John,Smith,Smith,21
John,42,42,42
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a Perl solution that you can integrate into a larger script (and doesn't quite so closely resemble line noise), and that correctly handles CSV data where a field contains a comma, I'd use the `Text::CSV` module:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $file = shift or die "Usage: $0 <file>\n";

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!\n";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
   my %h;
   $h{$_}++ for @{$row};
   for my $dup_field (grep { $h{$_} > 1 } keys %h)  {
      if (length $dup_field) {
          print $csv->string();
          next;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like perl and regex, then this looks good :
`perl -ne 'print if /(?:^|,)([^,]+),(?:.*,)?\1(?:,|$)/'`

If you need explanations :
`([^,]+)` matches a "word" (in that context, I use "word" to mean "the data of a row"), and `\1` will see if it is repeated. `(?:.*,)?` allows other words to be between the repetitions of your data. And finally `(?:^|,)` and `(?:,|$)` ensure that the 2 repeated words are the same, and no one is a substring of the other.